# How to handle memory management when passing pointers to library functions

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm working on a project in C++/CLI currently, and I'm trying to wrap my brain around memory allocation. In my code I need to call methods from an external library that I don't have the ability to edit or read the source code. A specific issues I've ran into is the following. They have a class something like this:

```
class Item {
public:
    void SetName(const char* name);
};
```

Nothing too unusual, it has a method for setting the name... but wait a minute... how am I supposed to free that char* pointer? If I call it from my code like this:

```
void MyMethod(Item* myItem){
    char* name = CallOtherMethodThatGivesMeTheName();
    myItem->SetName(name);
};
```

When am I supposed to deallocate name? I can't stay inside this function forever waiting until myItem no longer uses it, and I have absolutely no clue how the library has implemented SetName().

Should I just delete name within this scope? Won't that mean myItem no longer has a valid pointer though? Maybe I should use some sort of smart pointer? In general, is there a standard way to handle this situation?

And since I am using C++ / CLI, my actual method looks like the following, but I'm looking for a general solution (this might be wrong too).

```
void MyMethod(Item* myItem, String^ name){
    pin_ptr<const wchar_t> pinned_name = PtrToStringChars(name)
    myItem->SetName(pinned_name);
};
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is no standard; you have to just know what functions do with pointers. This is usually part of the library documentation.

Comment: If they don't explicitly say something about ownership in their documentation, I would assume the `const char*` will not be owned, but instead they make a copy of the array. That's usually how it's done, because by definition a raw pointer is not owning. In that case you can deallocate the pointer immediately after the call to `SetName()`.

Comment: You have to read the library's documentation.

Comment: Sadly the library has not documented this from what I can tell. The only interesting thing I noticed is that their methods explicitly use the __stdcall calling convention, which doesn't seem related.

Comment: Well, this question is not answerable then.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the CLI portion of your question, I provide the following answer. I don't think using CLI is relevant to the core of your question. What you really want to know is when the third party library deems it safe for you to release some allocated string you passed it.

Given the code you provided:

```
class Item {
public:
    void SetName(const char* name);
};
```

and assuming there is no documentation, I would assume the library makes an internal copy of a c-style string that you provide and that there is no reason to concern yourself with freeing it any more than you would normally. I make this assumption from the context. That would be the proper thing to do. Granted not all third party libraries do the "proper thing", but you cannot be omnipotent.

For example, I would assume:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    Item item;

    {
        std::string name("Sam");
        item.SetName(name.c_str());
    }

    // Carry on doing things with item...

    return 0;
}
```

works just fine, until I examine some behavior that says otherwise. If I am concerned about a third party library behaving poorly, then I test the above in a loop and watch the memory, or witness access violations, but not until I have reason to do so.

In the end:
) Read the documentation for the library.
) Ask on their user groups or forums. 
) If none is available, use intuition and context. 
) If something unexpected happens, then test.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the value of `name` **after** you called `SetName` and the library uses the originally provided value you know it has been copied.

Otherwise it uses always the current pointer and you cannot deallocate it safely due to the fact you don't know in which order the compiler releases the objects when the program ends.

Answer (score -2):

Usually you only "delete" what you create with "new".

Libraries that return data with pointers, work in two way:

1- Ask you to allocate memory and pass them the pointer (datatype * p)

2- Allocate for you and give you the pointer (return datatype *) or (argument datatype ** p) or (argument datatype * & p)

In first way you know when to free your memory.

In second way, when you finished working with data, you need to call another function from the same library to free the memory for you, pair functions like this pattern are quite common (open close) (alloc free) ...

Of course there can be other ways, so always reading documentation is the best.

In C++/CLI you don't delete objects defined with "^" sign, garbage-collector will take care of them.

Comment: My situation is case 1 then, since it's just a char* I create, but obviously my issue is that I actually don't know when to delete.

Also, I know I don't delete in C++/CLI, my concern was actually that the data may get moved after the pin_ptr goes out of scope. Or the caller could edit the string for some reason. Either one would invalid myItem's char* pointer.

Comment: "*In first way you know when to free your memory.*" - That's not true. It all depends on whether the library still hangs on to that pointer or not (either because it doesn't need it anymore or because it's made a copy). In the former case you can't just free the memory.

Comment: Actually your situation is case 2, defining char * is not allocating memory for text that this pointer will point.

Comment: Defining it isn't. But if I need to allocate the text dynamically on the heap then it certainly is case 1, and somewhere along the line it needs to be freed. Of course if my string is a literal then this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You can return from the function that you allocated memory without freeing it, you just need to keep the pointer with a none local variable, then when you are done with data (let's say in Item::~Item) you can free that memory:  delete[] m_name;

Comment: Right, but the issue is that I don't control the "Item" object. It may get passed around and used in a ton of other methods, but by that time I've already exited the scope of this function I no longer have a reference to my original string anyway.I assume the "Item" does, but its private anyway; so it'd be too late for me to free it manually.

Comment: You need to define a global char* gName; and copy name (local variable) to gName inside function: gName = name; this operation does not reallocate memory, you just have another pointer to that block.